# Cascading dropdown list in ng-admin

Tags: angularjs, dropdown, cascadingdropdown, cascading, ng-admin

I'm using ng-admin.
I have two dropdown lists in a page, one for Provinces and the other for cities.
I would like to populate choice of cities according to the value of the selected Province field. I can't load the whole list because it is humungous.
What's the best way to do it?
Here is my code:

```
dipendenti.creationView()
    .title('Aggiungi dipendente')
    .fields([
        nga.field('Nome')
            .validation({required: true })
            .cssClasses('col-sm-4'),
        nga.field('Cognome')
            .validation({required: true })
            .cssClasses('col-sm-4'),
        nga.field('anagrafica.idprovincia','reference')
                           .label('Provincia')
                           .targetEntity(admin.getEntity('province'))
                           .targetField(nga.field('id'))
                           .targetField(nga.field('nome'))
                           .validation({required: true })
                           .cssClasses('col-sm-4'),
        nga.field('anagrafica.idcitta','reference')
                           .label('Città')
                           .targetEntity(admin.getEntity('comuni'))
                           .targetField(nga.field('id'))
                           .targetField(nga.field('nome'))
                           .validation({required: true })
                            .permanentFilters({
                                provincia: 5}) //<- here shoud be retrieved automatically
                        //  .remoteComplete(true, {
                        //      refreshDelay: 300,
                            //// populate choices from the response of GET /posts?q=XXX
                            //  searchQuery: function(search) { return { provincia: search }; } //<- here with autocomplete
                            //  })
                            .cssClasses('col-sm-4')
```

I wonder if there is a way to inject a scope on the reference or the best practice for ng-admin...otherwise I think I shoud write an Angular directive...which is not exactly MY piece of cake...!
I've looked at the code generated and it is a bit complicated ( I think I should replicate it as the directive's template ) so I'd prefer to find an elegant way to do the job. 
Thank you very much...

Comment: show us your code!

Comment: You're right, I'ave added a snippet...

Comment: I need to know how to pass to permanent filters a dynamic value...

Comment: Anyone? Please help...